# looping period using php for loop but when i adding substr is not working

Tags: php

how to looping to get period list using php
this is my code

```
<?php

$start = 201901;
$end = 202012;

$result = [];

for($i=$start; $i<=$end; $i++){
    if($i==201913){
        $i=202001;
    }
    array_push($result,$i);
}



var_dump($result);
```

that code is working as my expectation but when i want to make more dynamic with change substr function it is not working
this is my change loop

```
for($i=$start; $i<=$end; $i++){
    if(substr($i,3,2) == 13){
        $i= (substr($i,3,2) + 1) * 100 + 1 ;
    }
    array_push($result,$i);
}

thank before for help
```

Comment: Why use integers? PHP has built in [date/time](https://www.php.net/datetime) functionality.

Comment: Please click [edit] and make your question more specific than "it is not working" - are you getting an error, it just not the result you expected? What result did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

To give an example of the use of the [date/time](https://www.php.net/datetime) functionality of PHP Jonnix was referring to:

```
<?php

$startDate  = date_create('2019-01-01');
$finishDate = date_create('2020-12-01');
$interval   = date_interval_create_from_date_string('1 months');

$result = [];

$date = $startDate;
while ($date < $finishDate) {
    date_add($date, $interval);
    $result[] = date_format($date, 'Ym');
}    

var_dump($result);
```

The output is:

```
array(23) {
  [0]=> string(6) "201902"
  [1]=> string(6) "201903"
  [2]=> string(6) "201904"
  .........
  [21]=> string(6) "202011"
  [22]=> string(6) "202012"
}
```

The output is a bit long, but this method clearly sticks to the correct number of months.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong start in your substr. You have wrote:

```
if(substr($i,3,2) == 13) {...
```

If you check like that, you compare the 3rd and 4th number of your int "start" which contains the 9 and 0. You should use the 4th and 5th which is 0 and 1.

```
if (substr($i, 4, 2) == 13) {...
```

Please correct me, if I'm wrong.